# Django update only blank rows in model instance

Tags: python, django, model

I'm looping through a list of dicts and creating models (journals) from dicts. They have a many to many relationship with Researcher.

Each dict looks like this

```
 {'abbreviation': 'Front. Artif. Intell. Appl.',
  'journal_type': 'k',
  'title': 'Frontiers in Artificial Intelligence and Applications'}
```

However, there are duplicates in this list, which is fine, I check manually to see if they exist, if they do, I dont create a new model for it.

BUT. The problem is, the entries in the list of dicts has duplicates with varying degrees of missing columns. Eg,

Entry 123

```
{'abbreviation': 'Front. Artif. Intell. Appl.',
      'journal_type': 'k',
      'title': 'Frontiers in Artificial Intelligence and Applications'}
```

Entry 124

```
{'abbreviation': 'Front. Artif. Intell. Appl.',
 'issn':123,
      'journal_type': 'k',
      'title': 'Frontiers in Artificial Intelligence and Applications'}
```

As you can see, 124 is more 'complete' than 123.

At the point of 123, I've already created the journal object from that hash. However, I want to update the **same** row with **only** **the new fields** from 124 (in this case, update the row with the issn)

What is the proper way to do this? :)

Comment: Your Entry 124 if is less of a `,` after `123` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find one column which is always present, which also can be considered as unique on database (consider LogicalKey column).

```
for entry in entries:
  try:
    record = Model.objects.get(logical_key = entry['logical_key')
    for k,v in entry.items():
      if record._meta.get_field(k) is None:
        setattr(record,k,v)
    record.save()
  except:
    Model.objects.create(field1=entry['field1'],...)
```

Comment: Yeah figured this just now, surprised django doesnt have an easier way to do this. Thanks! :)